# Python 3 BeautifulSoup4 search for text in source page

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I want to search for all '1' in the source code and print the location of that '1' ex: `<div id="yeahboy">1</div>` the '1' could be replaced by any other string. I want to see the tag around that string.

Comment: What do you mean by *the location of that '1'*?

Comment: @har07I just want to print all the locations of all '1' in the source code  1 can be replace by any other string

Comment: define "locations". Did you mean, you want to print the container element like : `<div id="yeahboy">1</div>`?

Comment: Give us a context please. Post minimal codes showing what the input HTML looks like, what variables you used to hold the `BeautifulSoup` object etc., then we can build on top of that focusing only to the core question that is finding text "1" and print the element

Comment: @har07 it is difficult for me to explain it to you but lets say there is a webpage -wikipedia- I want to search for the word 'banana' and print where that is or the different location that it  basicaly its a ctrl+f (kinda) I would like to see the tags around that string like my example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this *context* for example * :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<root>
<div id="yeahboy">1</div>
<div id="yeahboy">2</div>
<div id="yeahboy">3</div>
<div>
    <span class="nested">1</span>
</div>
</root>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
```

You can use `find_all()` passing [parameter `True`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#true) to indicate that you want only element nodes (instead of the child text nodes), and [parameter `text="1"`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-text-argument) to indicate that the element you want must have text content equals "1" -or any other text you want to search for- :

```
for element1 in soup.find_all(True, text="1"):
    print(element1)
```

Output :

```
<div id="yeahboy">1</div>
<span class="nested">1</span>
```

*) <sub>For OP: for future questions, try to give a context, just like the above context example. That will make your question more *concrete* and easier to answer -as people doesn't have to create context on his own, which may turn out to be not relevant to the situation that you actually have</sub>.

Comment: the thing is I do not know their location, I want to use the script to find them all

Comment: @bob Codes above demonstrates finding elements by text without prior knowledge about location of the elements . Any problem with that example?

Comment: It indeed worked but there is a but. It works if the text contains all the string. If I want to look at a part of a string it doesn't work eg:(this work)  `import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'http://www.editionsmosquito.com/exposition.php'
r= requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
for element1 in soup.find_all(True, text="Expositions"):
    print(element1)`  indeed this work but when I do this:
`for element1 in soup.find_all(True, text="Expo"):
    print(element1)` Even tho Exposition contains Expo, it doesn't print it, can you help me?